# Shouldn't this be undeleted?

Tags: support, status-declined, low-quality-posts, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949572/python-how-can-i-associate-a-function-to-a-button) was recently deleted. Though it's a question of low quality and not direct, the main error (the one with the `StringVar`)'s reason/cause hasn't been explained properly in other posts, and there are only a few questions that even are close to this.

Can the question be undeleted and edited so that it fits my answer (or my answer fits it, however)? The title could be the error and the body a shorter (as in MRE) version of the code (the parts related to Tkinter and the error caused by trying to `StringVar` in the wrong order) and the full code the OP posted after that saying that's the full code.

I forgot that I'm probably question-banned. I still don't understand why I'm still banned from asking questions.

Comment: If you think there's a missing canonical in there somewhere why not create that missing canonical and self answer it instead?

Comment: "Though it's a question of low quality" why we should undelete low quality content?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I've already answered that and don't want to write another 2 posts. I can edit the post if it gets undeleted.

Comment: I don't see a wall of code 240 lines long being useful to future searchers

Comment: @Braiam, I said it's a question of low quality because it was when deleted. It IMO can be improved by editing.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I said I can edit and improve it.

Comment: You don't want to write a new high quality question but you're perfectly happy to edit an old poor quality one?

Comment: @RobertLongson, not "happy" (not going to laugh like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU8kMcKQoik)), but to save the reputation for a thousand?

Comment: And because I've helped the OP get his 240 lines of code working? That's in my answer too. Only the OP's question (code) can *match* my answer?

Comment: That your code is specific for the question is irrelevant. If you have an answer whose general concepts are useful to many future visitors, than that is what matters most. I agree with @RobertLongson -- if you can find no decent canonical Q&A for the problem solved in your answer, then consider creating one. Or if one does exist, then consider contributing your own answer to it.

Comment: You being question banned is not relevant as to whether a question should be undeleted.

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes, but I can't ask a question and answer it to recreate the question.

Comment: In that case you need to read and work on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @RobertLongson, like, how am I supposed to improve these? Some of them should've been asked on Super User, and some are stupid and won't be helpful no matter how they can be improved by editing/anything, just like "the OP's question": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479777/is-there-any-folder-in-which-all-the-windows-system-files-are-stored-that-launch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649651/how-can-i-read-write-a-file-which-is-inside-an-exe

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder If you can't improve your existing questions, you can ask a new one in 6 months.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, doesn't 6 months sound a lot? A lot for me to ask a new question for this too?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder No, 6 months is not too long given the massive question quality problem SO has.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, ["This site (an SE site) is AIDS." "I thought, StackOverflow and its Meta is."](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/136744). If "there's a massive question quality problem" on SO, there's a lot more with it.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder - If your question banned you can wait 6 months, and then submit a question, and then answer your own question. I fail to see how reopening a question you admit is vague and rightly closed is a good idea. No, editing to such a degree, where it’s no long the original author’s question isn’t a viable solution

Comment: Here's a reasonable canonical for the error message in the image from revision 1 of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236857/python-tkinter-error-too-early-to-create-image

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, yes, but the error message is a bit different though the cause is the same. But a `StringVar` sounds more like a `var`iable and may be confused with a normal variable; it's usually forgotten that it's a part of Tkinter.

Comment: At the very least, it's a base for asking a better canonical. It comes across to me that many things could be "too early" in Tkinter (`StringVar`, `Image` etc.) with a common cause (root hasn't been instantiated yet) that could present in multiple ways (code out of order; code written in order in separate functions and thus executed out of order; instantiation missing altogether) and that these are *really all the same question*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend writing your own question rather than editing another user's deleted poor question into quality shape, for a few reasons:

1. It's your question, so you reap the reputation rewards.
2. You can self-answer it, and if you wish to, accept the answer after 48 hours have passed.
3. It doesn't involve a lot of effort on your part to write a new question outside of whatever effort you put into the question, but the community would be very involved in the case of editing to make suitable for un-deletion. When you edit a deleted question:

   - Other community members must engage with the post and agree that it is now fit for un-deletion.
   - It's also possible that others will disagree and keep the post in the deleted state, making your efforts all for naught.
   - If you don't have unilateral edit rights ([earned privilege at 2K+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), your edit could be rejected for [a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits).

   If the post was closed prior to deletion, *additional* community members must also agree to re-open the post before you can answer it.

---

[Your concern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419274/shouldnt-this-be-undeleted#comment918695_419274) is that you don't want to write two more posts, but if a post was deleted it will likely require a good amount of editing to improve its quality. You may also change the intent of the original author when making such substantial edits which is something to avoid. Since there is effort expended either way, and you are already planning on writing an answer, you might as well spare the headache of *maybe* getting the old post un-deleted and just write your own Q&A. This way, **the only community member involved is you** and the question/answer doesn't get caught up in the bureaucracy surrounding suggested edits and un-deletion (and re-opening, for closed-and-deleted questions).

Comment: I the case of that particular question I'd recommend against editing even more strongly - I don't see how one can make an edit that is acceptable - one would need to convert wall of code to MRE and that is huge no-no for edits (maybe ok for a popular question after proper meta discussion or maybe with 100K+ rep/multiple gold badges... but for random post, especially without 2K+ rep that suggested edit is 100% to be reverted, and possibly flagged for mod attention)

Comment: Wait. I forgot that I'm probably question-banned.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder: Are you or aren't you? It does look like your last few questions were not well received, it may serve you well to try to understand how to ask better questions. You can always ask another meta question if you are looking for insight in improving your questions.

Comment: [I've already asked one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418070/how-am-i-supposed-to-improve-my-questions-why-am-i-banned-from-asking-questions), but that wasn't well received too, LOL.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder It looks like you did [receive feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418070/how-am-i-supposed-to-improve-my-questions-why-am-i-banned-from-asking-questions#comment909712_418070) which you rejected stating "you don't care".

Comment: @Bender, but how am I supposed to "improve" that? IMO, deleting it is the best way.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder - If you cannot improve that one singular question you improve any question you can. Your question ban isn’t due to a singular question.